# How to use a custom adapter for AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview, custom-adapter

I am using an AutoCompleteTextView with a custom adapter, but the adapter does not seem to do anything. When I type in a couple letters, the drop down list does not show. I insert an ArrayList of some random words into the adapter. I also made sure I actually set the adapter to the textview, but nothing happened. When I used an ArrayAdapter instead, it worked. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

**Here is My Adapter**

```
package com.chappota.weather.list.model;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Pranav on 11/10/2014.
 */
public class CityDropDownAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

ArrayList<String> mList;
Context mContext;

public CityDropDownAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> list) {
    mList = list;
    mContext = ctx;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View mView = convertView;
    if (mView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null);
    }

    TextView suggestion = (TextView) mView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    suggestion.setText(mList.get(position));
    suggestion.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    return mView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new CityFilter();
}

private class CityFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
        return (resultValue.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {
            ArrayList<String> mData = mList;
            ArrayList<String> mSuggestions = mList;

            mSuggestions.clear();

            //Check for similarities in data from constraint
            for (String value : mData) {
                if (value.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    mSuggestions.add(value);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, value + " contains " + constraint.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, value + " does not " + constraint.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = mSuggestions;
            filterResults.count = mSuggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Can Someone please tell me what I did wrong, and how I should fix it? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what actually you wanna do? why don't you use an ArrayAdapter if it works?

Comment: for some reason, the text color of the drop down list is white instead of black, so i need a custom adapter to fix it

Comment: So use a custom layout and pass it to ArrayAdapter constructor

Comment: Thank you! That really helped, I can't believe I forget to do this earlier. But, I have another question - If the solution weren't so simple, what would have made my code above work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving reference over here,

```
            ArrayList<String> mData = mList;
            ArrayList<String> mSuggestions = mList;
```

And then clearing it,

```
           mSuggestions.clear();
```

That's why loop has no data and it was not working.

Instead declare new object, like this,

```
            ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>(mList);
            ArrayList<String> mSuggestions = new ArrayList<String>(mList);
```